# Substring extract from string in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring, amazon-redshift

The following query extracts the last two parts from a url. I want to extract the second last part from the url excluding the last.

```
SELECT substring(url,'/[^/]+/[^/]+$') FROM url_time;
```

Suppose I give input as `Input : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` then I wish to get `Output : /questions`

Sorry if it is a trivial question . I have not been able to get to the required solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[regexp_replace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html) and capture groups will do it:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ( url,'^.*/([^/]+)/[^/]+$', '\1' ) FROM url_time;
```

The initial `^.*` consumes the beginning of the url. The parenthesis `()` around the first `[^/]+` indicate a capture group, `\1` replaces the entire match with the value of the capture group in output.

Comment: SELECT regexp_replace('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask','/([^/])+/[^/]+$','\1') AS action; gives me http://stackoverflow.coms as the answer as of now. I am trying to experiment with it though.

Comment: Yeah, I caught that too, answered before I tested. See my edit.